# Valgrind memory leak

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

```
Record* MyClass::get_record (int id)
{
    Record* rec = new Record();
    Record* compressed_rec;

    /* ... code that gets compressed_rec into memory ... */

    compressed_rec->decompress(rec);

    return rec;
}
```

This function is always used like this:

```
Record* rec = my_class_instance.get_record (id);
show_contents_of(rec);
delete rec;
```

`valgrind` says that i'm leaking memory on the first line (`Record* rec = new Record();`). Why?

Comment: What is in the code that has been snipped?

Comment: Either it is a false positive, or the leak is elsewhere.

Comment: concerning memory leaks I would trust valgrind, and say that you have a code path that somehow does not delete the memory (e.g. via exceptions). Since there is just so much code lacking, we can not tell you anything more but guess. And wonder why you don't use smart pointers, which would likely solve the problem...

Comment: hm whats with your compressed_rec pointer? is it freed somewhere :-)?

Comment: @Najzero, yes, inside the function.

Comment: Does `Record` have any dynamically allocated resources that are not de-allocated on destruction?

Answer (score 0):

> valgrind says that i'm leaking memory on the first line (Record* rec = new Record();). Why?

Does it show the `Record` itself is being leaked, or something else allocated inside `Record::Record`?

If the former, either some return path from `MyClass::get_record` leaks it, or the *caller* leaks it. Switching to use a smart pointer would fix both cases:

```
std::unique_ptr<Record> MyClass::get_record (int id)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Record> rec(new Record());
    ...
    return rec;
}
```

If it's the latter case, that either means the whole Record is being leaked (see above), or its destructor is buggy. Again, try keeping any dynamically allocated members in smart pointers.